# Installing scipy in Python 3.5 on 32-bit Windows 7 Machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have been trying to install Scipy onto my Python 3.5 (32-bit) install on my Windows 7 machine using the pre-built binaries from: 
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs

I have, in order, installed the following libraries

```
numpy‑1.10.1+mkl‑cp35‑none‑win32.whl
scipy‑0.16.1‑cp35‑none‑win32.whl
```

Then, when trying to use the installed packages I get the following erros

```
from scipy import sparse
< ... Complete error trace ommitted ... >
packages\scipy\sparse\csr.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

However, if i follow the same process for Python 3.4 replacing the installers with:

```
numpy‑1.10.1+mkl‑cp35‑none‑win32.whl
scipy‑0.16.1‑cp35‑none‑win32.whl
```

Everything seems to work.  Are there additional dependencies or install packages that I am missing for the Python 3.5 install?

Comment: I would recommend you installing [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/). It provides updated pre-built binaries for most of the python packages, and is very easy to manage/upgrade any package.

Comment: @imaluengo Thanks for pointing me towards Anaconda, I found the download page here simplified the process: https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you pay attention to this line from the link you provided:

> Many binaries depend on NumPy-1.9+MKL and the Microsoft Visual C++
>   2008 (x64, x86, and SP1 for CPython 2.6 and 2.7), Visual C++ 2010
>   (x64, x86, for CPython 3.3 and 3.4), or the Visual C++ 2015 (x64 and
>   x86 for CPython 3.5) redistributable packages.

Download the corresponding Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package which should be [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) one based on your description.

I had a similar problem, can't recall the exact issue, and I download the one for my system and it worked fine. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: That does appear to be the issue, however your link was incorrect, it is pointing at the 2010 version.  The Link I downloaded and installed from was:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

If you wouldn't mind editing your answer, I'll mark it as the answer

Comment: You're right, you said 3.5. I had 3.4 in mind the whole time. The answer has been changed.

Comment: I was missing the 2015 Redistributable. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly helpful: trying to pip install `scipy-0.18.0rc2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` (downloaded from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) on 64-bit windows 7 with Python 3.5 failed with a "file does not exist/not a valid wheel filename" error.

From various hints obtained from here and elsewhere I found that renaming the file to: `scipy-0.16.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl` allowed it to install.

Answer (score 1):

Pull up the command window (search for it in the start button), then enter

```
pip install numpy
```

and

```
pip install scipy‑0.16.1‑cp35‑none‑win32.whl
```

then it should let you know in the command window if it was successfully downloaded, if you have python 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

I had a question that turned out to be a duplicate of this one here:

[ImportError: DLL load failed: when importing statsmodels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33733400/importerror-dll-load-failed-when-importing-statsmodels?noredirect=1#comment55247406_33733400)

I actually solved this and other issues related to installing packages (such as statsmodels) by using Anaconda installer for Python 3.5.