# from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline: Importerror

Tags: python, scipy, windows-8.1, importerror, jetbrains-ide

Set-up:
      OS: Win8.1 64bit,
      IDE: JetBrains PyCharm,
      Python: 3.5,
      [SciPy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) and [NumPy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy): cp35 64bit whl files installed using pip

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N = 1000
n = N/10
s = np.random.normal(size=N)   # generate your data sample with N elements
p, x = np.histogram(s, bins=n) # bin it into n = N/10 bins
x = x[:-1] + (x[1] - x[0])/2   # convert bin edges to centers
f = UnivariateSpline(x, p, s=n)
plt.plot(x, f(x))
plt.show()
```

Error report:

```
C:\Users\gakadam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe C:/Users/gakadam/PycharmProjects/pdf_curve/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gakadam/PycharmProjects/pdf_curve/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
  File "C:\Users\gakadam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\__init__.py", line 145, in <module>
    from .interpolate import *
  File "C:\Users\gakadam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 16, in <module>
    import scipy.special as spec
  File "C:\Users\gakadam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 601, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
  File "scipy\special\_ufuncs.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.special._ufuncs (scipy\special\_ufuncs.c:26071)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I can follow the error to _unfuncs.pyx file but I have no idea how to rectify that. Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can search stackoveflow first to find answers to similar questions, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600302/installing-scipy-in-python-3-5-on-32-bit-windows-7-machine

Comment: Sorry for duplicate question. Missing VC++ files helped. I used the search here but I will be more exhaustive next time. Thank you.