# sklearn/sci-py on Windows (Python 3.5) DLL errors on import

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am trying to use `sklearn` in Windows 7 with Python 3.5, via the pre-compiled Windows binaries at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

I have installed

- dask-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- scikit_learn-0.17-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
- scipy-0.16.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
- numpy-1.9.3+mkl-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
- pandas-0.17.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl

without any errors at install time. Following another SO thread with the same error, I made sure that C:/python35 is both in my `Path` and is set as the `PYTHONPATH`.

I also have Visual Studio 2013 C++ installed.

When I go to `import sklearn` I get this error:

```
C:\Users\user>python
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py", line 213, in <module>
    from .csr import *
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csr.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

***Update: BrianCain's suggestion to upgrade Visual Studio C++ to version 2015 worked!***

Comment: Have you tried the solution outlined here?  The problem sounds very similar to the one I encountered.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600302/installing-scipy-in-python-3-5-on-32-bit-windows-7-machine

Comment: @BrianCain Good question! I didn't see that post, however, I do already have Visual Studio 2013 C++ installed. I will try installing the 2015 version just to be sure.

Comment: @BrianCain !!! The 2015 version did the trick!

Comment: Also, there is no official 32 bit scipy and numpy packages, so if you install them through PIP or from official site - everything will work ok.

Comment: @Olologin I am on 64-bit but it's interesting that you mentioned PIP -- that doesn't work for Windows, right? If it does or can that would be amazing. I thought everyone tells you to use that unofficial site for binaries if you're on Windows (but I'd love to find a better practice because it's a huge pain).

Comment: @y0gapants, i've never used pip in Windows, but look here, it should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

After installing you can manage your packages with pip list/ pip install packagename. In most cases it's a best solution for this. Also look at "conda" scientific distribution, i often see that folks use it in windows.

Comment: @Olologin Cool! Thanks. Yea, I will happily go back to using Conda as soon as they gear up for 3.5. I'm one of those people who always have to have the latest version of a language, even if there's not a good logical reason.