# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. Python+Face recognition

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, face-recognition, pythonxy

I run a python program about Face Recognition and I get this problem. please anyone can suggest me how I can fix this problem. sorry for my bad English skill. Thank you.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\FaceRecognition.py", line 1, in <module>
    from facerec.feature import Fisherfaces
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facerec\feature.py", line 44, in <module>
    from facerec.util import asColumnMatrix
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facerec\util.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scipy import ndimage
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\__init__.py", line 161, in <module>
    from .filters import *
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\filters.py", line 37, in <module>
    from scipy.misc import doccer
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from scipy.special import comb, factorial, factorial2, factorialk
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 627, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Python 2.7.10 (32-bits) 
Windows 7 
numpy-1.11.0+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win32 
pip-8.0.3-py2.py3-none-any 
scipy-0.17.0-cp27-none-win32 
opencv 2.4.11

Comment: Did you install the correct version of scipy? Did you install all its dependencies? Since you didn't specify any details, it's difficult to give a concrete answer, but there have been [similar questions before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600302/installing-scipy-in-python-3-5-on-32-bit-windows-7-machine)

Comment: thank you for your comment Dan. I have... 
Python 2.7.10 (32-bits)
Windows 7
numpy-1.11.0+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win32
pip-8.0.3-py2.py3-none-any
scipy-0.17.0-cp27-none-win32
opencv 2.4.11
....
thank again Dan for that similar questions :D I will try to fix this.