# Scipy Dll load error

Tags: python, numpy, dll, scipy

I have been encountering a dll load error when importing the SciPy module.

```
 Import scipy.sparse.linalg
 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have read multiple posts regarding this issue and all of them point to the same solution. To install the 'numpy+mkl' from 
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/   I already have installed the .whl file for numpy+mkl and then I installed scipy from the same link (because pip install scipy had been giving the  No Lapack/blas resource found error)

I'm using Python3.5 32 bit. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing scipy in Python 3.5 on 32-bit Windows 7 Machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600302/installing-scipy-in-python-3-5-on-32-bit-windows-7-machine)

Comment: I just found that out right after posting this. Thanks anyway