# Error intalling scipy for python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

[image]Got an error installing scipy package (see attachement) from prompt. Windows 7, 64bit, Python 3.5.1. Also tryed `scipy-0.19.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` but got a `scipy-0.19.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform` response. So how to find the supported wheel? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Didn't find the way to install scipy package itself but installed Anaconda and made it as a default PyCharm Python interpreter, scipy imports properly now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing scipy in Python 3.5 on 32-bit Windows 7 Machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600302/installing-scipy-in-python-3-5-on-32-bit-windows-7-machine)

Answer (score 0):

Update you pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

And then try

```
pip install scipy
```

Comment: yes, I tryed scipy installation after pip apgrading, it gave me the result on the screenshot

Comment: please try "pip install openblas" and try again pip install scipy

Comment: This is a duplicate of many Qs. In short: can't just usr pip on Windows. Use Gohlke wheels or Anaconda